# open source custom tooltip (callout) control/code for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Looking for a custom tooltip (typical yellow baloon callout) on click of an anchor tag. The tooltip should appear and remain in view until the cross button on the tooltip is clicked.

Just looking for a tried and tested open source solution. Tried googling this but most of the tooltip [...*missing info?*...]

Ajax control toolkit has the calloutvalidator which seems like a good choice but is tied up to be used for validation tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of many good open source server side controls. But you should take a look at these:

- http://www.obout.com/flyout/example_Googlemap_tooltip.aspx - Free for commercial and personal use
- http://aspalliance.com/1686 - Creating a Custom Tooltip Ajax Extender Control
- http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/ - qTip for jQuery. It's not an asp.net control, but could work well for you.